# Existing equivalents of Deprecated Classes in android

Tags: java, android

Android 2.3.3

How do we find the new classes that are equivalent to the deprecated classes in android. Let' say,  `Contacts.People.CONTENT_URI` is replaced with `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI`. Now how do I know, what are the equivalents of `Contacts.PeopleColumns.NAME`, `Contacts.Intents.Insert.NAME` and `Contacts.People.Phones.CONTENT_DIRECTORY` and so on. Do we have a list somewhere? or How do I go about looking for these changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of these mentioned have their page in the Android developers documentation. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Contacts.PeopleColumns.html), [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Contacts.People.Phones.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Contacts.Intents.Insert.html).

They all say the following:

> This interface was deprecated in API level 5. See ContactsContract

Meaning that you should check out [ContactsContract](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html) for a suitable replacement to those three and other deprecated interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find detailed infos about Android 2.3.3 version changes: https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/10/changes.html

Answer (score 0):

Adding more informations to @ColorWP.com answer, you could find here the report of what has been added/removed etc for each API level (here's the list for the last one).

http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/17/changes.html